# Mnemonics for centures or any other longer periods, like Zodiac signs other than Chinese?

Tags: calendar

I would like to have compatible mnemonics to remember historical dates.

"Compatible" means it should not be my own mnemonics, but something, related with old cultural and historical symbols, like Zodiac signs.

Are there any other "zodiacs" or "calendars", which have longer time periods, than Chinese zodiac, which associates animal with each year? Are there any associations for longer time units, like centuries?

I would prefer signs for "round" periods like centuries or millennia.

Comment: As the song goes, this is the Age of Aquarius. The cycle of [astrological ages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrological_age) repeats approximately every 26,000 years, with each individual age lasting a couple thousand years.

Comment: I'd feel that I understood the question better if it were clearer how this related to the study or practice of history.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace see my update please

Answer (score 2):

### Chinese Calendar Cycles

The Chinese traditional lunar calendar has a cycle of sixty years. Within this there are a twelve year sub-cycle, during which the year of the sheep, for example, recurs after twelve years.

As [Semaphore](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/4935/semaphore) commented below, *"The 12 animal signs were associated with the 12 `earthly-branches`, which combines with 10 `celestial-stems` to form the sexagenary `stems-and-branches` cycle"*. This also meant there were 60 uniquely named years.

### Mayan Calendar Cycles

The [Maya Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_calendar#Calendar_Round) has 19 Haab' months and a cycle of 52 Haab' years or 18,980 days.

[image]

The [Long count](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_calendar#Long_Count) calendar has a cycle of 63,081,429 years.

```
Table of Long Count units
unit            period                    Days  Approximate
                                                Solar Years
1 K'in                                       1   
1 Winal         20 K'in                     20   
1 Tun           18 Winal                   360           1
1 K'atun        20 Tun                   7,200          20
1 B'ak'tun      20 K'atun              144,000         394
1 Piktun        20 B'ak'tun          2,880,000       7,885
1 Kalabtun      20 Piktun           57,600,000     157,704
1 K'inchiltun   20 Kalabtun      1,152,000,000   3,154,071
1 Alautun       20 K'inchiltun  23,040,000,000  63,081,429
```